# In Excel, how do I add a footer to the last page only?

Tags: excel, vba

**UPDATED 3/10/2015 @ 4:03PM**

I'm trying to add a footer to the last page only in Excel, but crazily enough there isn't any options to do so within the program...you can only specify a custom footer for the first page and nothing else!

I figured the only way I could achieve this would be through the use of VBA macros, but unfortunately any information online regarding the implementation of this functionality is easily 10+ years old and not really helping.

Because of the limitations of the footer option, I thought I would try a different approach, which was to add a row at the bottom of the last page.

I have the following code...

```
Sub pageBreak()

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

rows(LastRow & ":200").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M$" & LastRow + Unknown Value

HowMany = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count

WhatRow = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(HowMany).Location.Row - 4

Range("A" & CStr(WhatRow) & ":L" & CStr(WhatRow)).Merge

rows(WhatRow).RowHeight = 54
rows(WhatRow).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
rows(WhatRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
rows(WhatRow).WrapText = True

Range("A" & CStr(WhatRow)) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

This almost works, but the catch is that it depends on page breaks being present, so let's say your content ended on page 2, you have to manually pull down the print-area to show a page 3, so there is a page break between 2/3 and then the code can be placed above it on page 2. So in my code, where it says `Unknown Value`, that has to be the amount needed between the LastRow and the triggering of the next page-break. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it myself and here is the final code:

```
Sub addDisclaimer()

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

rows(LastRow + 1 & ":200").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M$" & LastRow + 50

HowMany = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count

WhatRow = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(HowMany).Location.Row - 4

Range("A" & CStr(WhatRow) & ":L" & CStr(WhatRow)).Merge

rows(WhatRow).RowHeight = 54
rows(WhatRow).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
rows(WhatRow).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
rows(WhatRow).WrapText = True

Range("A" & CStr(WhatRow)) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

FinalRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M" & FinalRow

Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA, just select the sheet you want it on and go to Page Setup, select the Header/Footer tab and click on the "Custom Header" or "Custom Footer" button. It will only assign it to the active sheet.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue...multiple pages and only have the footer appear on the last one, because by default Excel puts it on every page.